# gpgpu on cuda and opengl

Tags: cuda

I have been working with CUDA recently. I am just wondering if there is any performance difference between CUDA and Opengl in terms of general purpose computing. I am currently working on a GTX 580.

Comment: BTW: You are aware that OpenCL and OpenGL are not the same thing, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is probably "it depends".

In pure floating point or integer performance terms it shouldn't matter much whether you use GLSL or something more "modern", but CUDA and OpenCL expose hardware features like pointers, shared memory, communication and synchronization between threads, and the grid/block virtualization of compute domains which are pretty crucial to achieving good performance on compute workloads. There are lots of algorithms which would be either difficult or impossible to implement in shader language that are efficiently implemented in literally a handful of lines of code in OpenCL or CUDA.